# Conditional Execution - Launching Persistent Sub-Processes and Coroutines

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Conditional execution is used in Bash to control the flow of a script on the basis of the exit status of a subprocess.  However, there are situations when a subprocess (application) is launched in the background, to be used for interactive purposes, so there is no exit and no exit status, until it is closed.

Consider some examples, say launching a pdf viewer, *mupdf*.  Consider the first case with a file that exists, example.pdf:

```
$ mupdf example.pdf &
[1] 16220
```

That works, so let's try conditional execution:

```
$ mupdf example.pdf & && echo TRUE
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&&'
```

Hmmm.  Ok, let's try another (contrived) way, trying to avoid errors:

```
$ if mupdf example.pdf &; then echo TRUE; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
```

How about:

```
$ if (mupdf example.pdf &); then echo TRUE; fi
TRUE
```

That looks promising, But then we try the second case, with a file that does not exist:

```
$ mupdf nofile.pdf &
[1] 16282
$ error: cannot open nofile.pdf
error: cannot load document 'nofile.pdf'
mupdf: error: cannot open document

$ if (mupdf nofile.pdf &); then echo TRUE; fi
TRUE
$  error: cannot open nofile.pdf
error: cannot load document 'nofile.pdf'
mupdf: error: cannot open document
```

That construct is not working either.  So the usual approach to conditional execution does not work because there is no exit status.  But I noted that a pid is initially created in both successful and unsuccessful cases (*mupdf* does not open in the second case - launching ultimately fails).

So try another approach, wait to see what happens with the background pid, so we put together the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# usage: ./show <file>.pdf

mupdf "$1" &>/dev/null &
sleep 2
if kill -0 $! &>/dev/null
then 
  echo TRUE
else
  echo FALSE
fi

# end file
```

And test the first case:

```
$ ./show example.pdf  # case 1
[1] 16602
TRUE
```

That's OK.  Now the second case:

```
$ ./show nofile.pdf   # case 2
[2] 16699
[2]+  Exit 1                  mupdf nofile.pdf &> /dev/null
FALSE
```

Well that works too.  But this seems a very convoluted way to check the process and may fail if the launch takes more time (more than  2 seconds).  So my question becomes, is there a better (cleaner) way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you trying to get the exit status of a command before it exits?

Comment: @adonis Trying to get the _launch status_ before it exits, to see if it launched successfully.  For example a pdf viewer that would remain open to display while the rest of the script continues, I'm trying to ensure that it launches successfully before moving on to the rest of the script.

Comment: are you sure you're not trying to test if *`nofile.pdf`* exists?

Comment: @mikeserv That would have been the quick solution for this specific problem, but I decided to examine this more generally because the script I'm working on launches several different types of background processes (coroutines), some windowed, some not.  That's why I decided to post it on _unix.stackexchange.com_ - the general case becomes an interesting problem, that could be quite important for many scripts.

Comment: i dont know how your script can reliably test for successful execution without either 1) enumerating and testing for prerequisites for successful execution or 2) waiting for and evaluating a return. it seems to me like simply considering the absence of immediately evident error is bound to disappoint eventually.

Comment: @mikeserv In my case I am also launching custom C++ coroutines for data analysis and modelling - these rely upon complex input files - the files exist so this could be tested, but the launch will fail if anything is wrong with the data of the input file, or if anything is wrong with the structure of the data file (probably true of _mupdf_ too). So testing for a successful launch (as opposed to a successful exit condition) becomes important.  I suppose that the heading 'Conditional Execution' is misleading - I'm looking for the same bash syntax approach, but not based upon the exit condition.

Comment: if they're *your* routines then you know best, but it seems like if they are then you should integrate a little better and actually get them to report to the parent in some definitely identifiable way. in the event of an immediate error you should at least, i think, raise the signal rather than simply test for existence of the process - like `{ mupdf some.pdf || kill -"$(($?&127))" "$$"; } &`

Comment: That is excellent advice, thank you, and your solution looks to be much better - I haven't seen the construct `"$(($?&127))"` (specifically why the bitwise operator `&127` is needed) could you explain how it works, or provide a link? Could you post the above as a solution with a little background?

Comment: Well, POSIX states that all returns above 128 are reserved to indicate receipt of a signal. And so the `&` bitwise op will strip any eighth bit which might have been added to the return. Since you're raising with `kill` anyway, whatever you do is going to be signal - you can't help that. You really should do *more* testing than that - for example  `kill -127 0; command ""; echo "$?"`. My linux system only handles signal numbers 1-64, so `kill -"$(($?&63))" pid`...? Try `kill -l` for a name list, or `set -x "$((x=0))"; while trap "" "$((x+=1))"; do trap; trap - "$x"; done"` maybe.

Comment: @mikeserv Very well explained.  You've helped me learn another important technique that I've not thought about before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've located a number of similar topics to this one that consider using such things as **xdotool** and **wmctl** for the purpose of testing the launch of a persistent windowed application or other persistent sub-process.  But using these seems like an unnecessary complication. The solution below would permit conditional execution of a persistent sub-process.  It utilizes a sleep duration of half a second.  If the sub-process of interest were to require longer to successfully launch then this duration would need to be increased accordingly.

Bash source file **launch**

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

# launch : will allow launching a windowed application or persistent
# sub-process in the background so that conditional execution can be
# applied to determine whether or not it has launched successfully -
# dependencies: GNU coreutils (sleep), util-Linux (kill)

# usage: ./launch process arg_1 .. arg_n && echo TRUE || echo FALSE

$@ &>/dev/null & sleep 0.5 && kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null

# end file
```

So that:

```
$ ./launch mupdf example.pdf && echo TRUE || echo FALSE
TRUE

$ ./launch mupdf nofile.pdf && echo TRUE || echo FALSE
FALSE
```

---

As a postcript to this information, I thought it would be useful to include the advice of *mikeserv* in the comments to the opening post.

Whereas the above construct accomplishes the immediate task, *mikeserv* points out that it could lead to other problems in that it does not propagate the signal to the calling script; it instead ignores and discards it.  This is a very important observation.

Signals are a key element of interprocess communication, and can lead to the possibility of event driven scripts.  So for more robust and effective scripts, *mikeserv* suggests the following to catch the signal so that it can be propagated:

```
{ mupdf some.pdf || kill -"$(($?&127))" "$$"; } &
```

where `$?&127` permits actioning 1 to 128 possible signals (POSIX), my Debian system has 64, so the signal mask could be `$?&63` instead.

---

So as a concluding remark, for very simple scripts, where interprocess communication is not of interest, the proposed *launch* can be useful, but for anything more, especially where interprocess communication is important, capture (and propagate) the signal, as advised by *mikeserv*.

Answer (score -1):

As a one-liner:

```
mupdf example.pdf & echo mupdf is now in the background; wait $! && echo FINISHED successfully
```

Comment: I believe that you didn’t read the same question that I did.

Comment: You are correct. I got so focused on OP's difficulty in controlling background processes that I forgot about addressing getting its exit status. Will edit.